# How do I create a react card with an image and text wrapped around?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to create a bootstrap-react component. I want to make a card with an image to the left where the text is wrapped around on the right side and the bottom but I can't get it to work.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

function BasicExample() {
 return (
   <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
     <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
     <Card.Body>
       <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
       <Card.Text>
         Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
         bulk of the card's content.
       </Card.Text>
       <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
     </Card.Body>
   </Card>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

This is the card that I am using and trying to convert but I also have a separate css file. I have tried flexbox, grid, and float but nothing seems to work inside the card.